# RSSOwl was unable to create a browser for reading news

Tags: rss

I'm trying to launch RSSOwl ( Version: 2.2.1 / Build Id: 2013-12-30 ) on my Ubuntu ( 64 Bit ). Twice, I'm download latest RSSOwl from here http://www.rssowl.org/download

There is such error:

```
RSSOwl was unable to create a browser for reading news. 
Please refer to the FAQ for further help.

Click 'Ok' to open the FAQ now.
```

According to FAQ: http://www.rssowl.org/help#item_6j

```
Download XULRunner 1.9 Runtime
Extract it to any directory that RSSOwl can read
Add a new startup property to rssowl named 
    -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=[XULRunner Runtime Directory]
Start RSSOwl and it will pick up the browser from the provided location
```

I can't understand this point: `Start RSSOwl and it will pick up the browser from the provided location`

I've extract tgz of XULRunner to `/usr/src`:

Now, I'm launch RSSOwl in next manner:

`./RSSOwl  -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/usr/src/xulrunner/xulrunner/`

And nothing works...

I'm also trying to select browser directly `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox` in the settings ( Edit -> Preferences ), too wrong.

`Use the embedded browser` - too wrong. The same error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found solution [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/rssowl/discussion/296910/thread/60f335c7/):

For my installation it looks like:

```
sudo ln -fs /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhunspell-1.3.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhunspell-1.2.so.0
```

Comment: Ubuntu18: `sudo ln -fs /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhunspell-1.6.so.0.0.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhunspell-1.2.so.0`. Basically one has to find the latest `libhunspell` on the system and create a symlink that refers to  `libhunspell-1.2.so.0`. Ensure that the symlink really exists.

Answer (score 7):

I found a more profound/prescribed - but in core of course the same - manual to his problem here: http://whilesurfing.blogspot.de/2012/06/make-rssowl-work-with-mint-13-maya.html

Sadly, the author of RSSOwl himself did not come up yet with a new patched version to get rid for good of this hassle. Even long time users changed to other, less functional software, because of it. It's really a shame.

Answer (score 0):

### Ubuntu 16

(Maybe works for other versions)

1. Create link

   ```
   sudo ln -fs /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhunspell-1.3.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhunspell-1.2.so.0
   ```
2. Restart **RSSOwl**